# Custom Slim Not Found Handler depending upon route

Tags: php, slim

In Slim, we're able to create custom Not Found handlers by assigning them to the Container.

This is great, but we need to be able to define a custom handler based on the current route group. So for example, please consider the following route definitions:

```
$app->group('/api', function() use ($app) {

});

$app->group('/', function() use ($app) {

});
```

When using the `/api` group, we want the Not Found handler to be defined as follows:

```
$container['notFoundHandler'] = function ($c)
{
    return function( $request, $response ) use ( $c )
    {
        return $response->withStatus(404)
                        ->withJSON([
                            'statusCode'  => 404,
                            'errorCode'   => 1001,
                            'description' => $c->get('errors')->get( 1001 ),
                            'timestamp'   => date('c')
                        ]);
    };
};
```

But when using the base route (`/`), we want to use a different HTML handler. Has anyone successfully assigned different handlers based upon route group in Slim 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no concept of multiple not found handlers. It is implemented as single service in container.

However your one handler can contain logic just fine. Native [`NotFound`](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.x/Slim/Handlers/NotFound.php) handler does varied conditional output for accepted content type, for example.

Your single handler could easily check for any necessary context in `$request` and modify return accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up doing in the end actually.